# Setting Time Zone Per Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Any idea how I can use the time zone generated from a location to create a new record with that respective zipcode?

I have created a service object to help pull the zipcode information.

I am able to use this info in the terminal to set the zip code but it doesn't work when I try a before_save or before_create hook.

```
class ServiceObject
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.get_timezone_name(location)
    z = GoogleTimeZone.fetch(location.latitude, location.longitude)
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo(z.time_zone_id)
  end
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  #name - String
  #start_time - DateTime
  #end_time - DateTime
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  geocoded_by :full_address
  before_create :zoned

  private
  def zoned
    Time.zone = ServiceObject.get_time_zone(self.location)
  end

end
```

I also tried to use the date time attribute [gem](https://github.com/einzige/date_time_attribute) to set an event's time zone. Again this works in the console but not with a call back.  Records are not created via a browser but rather in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post I wrote on timezones with rails: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

There are two different ways to accomplish what you want:

- `Time.use_zone` block when saving data
- use `in_time_zone` when displaying data

I recommend you save the timezone on your location, update it if the long/lat changes; it looks like your Event and Location example above is flipped? Event should have a start and end, not location?

```
class Location
  has_many :events

  geocoded_by :full_address
  before_save :set_time_zone

  private

  def set_time_zone
    if new_record? || latitude_changed? || longitude_changed?
      self.time_zone = ServiceObject.get_time_zone(self)
    end
  end
end

class Event
  belongs_to :location
end
```

then in the console or controller code

```
location = Location.last
Time.use_zone(location.time_zone) do
  location.events << Event.new({ ... })
end
```